# FTDI exchange RX/TX

Tags: pcb, usb, ftdi

I have built a PCB with an FTDI FT231X to convert UART to USB. 
Now RX and TX are switched by mistake. Is there a way to exchange them in the software?

Comment: RX/TX are hard wired and not part of the configuration options for that chip.

Comment: What does the data sheet say?

Comment: Cut the traces, solder wires. No SW solution here.

Comment: ^ easiest and quickest way, beside reviewing you damn gerbers

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot swap RX and TX from within the software. They are hardware connections, and each driver/receiver is configured (in hardware) as such. Your best option (or only option), as Eugene Sh suggested, is to cut the traces on the PCB that are swapped, and solder in a couple of wires instead that swap the signals.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, that PCB is screwed up. Hope your FTDI is not in a QFN package at least.

For next time, put serial resistor everywhere you can. It comes with some assembly extra cost, but until you gain confidence it will allow easy debug. Well, easier than cutting traces.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. I hoped for a nicer solution ;-)

Comment: Good for you! After same mistake in my first board, in second i prepared four resistors to avoid wires